# Bootstrap Mobile Navigation Dropdown Jumping on Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently developing a site that is almost done, however I am having an odd issue with the navigation on mobile.

The menu is collapsed using Bootstrap 3's collapse js. Everything works great, except when you open the menu it does not render my custom css immediately. It seems to open the menu, then jumps to the correct position and coloring. When you open the menu it starts on the right side, with the incorrect background color, then jumps to the correct positioning/color.

You can view the site here: http://brookmanville.com/

This issue happens regardless of browser or mobile device.

Comment: If you change your float left to float none then that did the trick for me. As far as the background-color, you are assigning the color to the finished class. Therefore, that class is not assigned until AFTER the entire animation is complete, therefore causing it to load late. Make sense?

Comment: @KyleHawk, yup ".navbar-collapse.in{background-color:rgba(18,30,43,.89)}"

Comment: ^thanks I was just about to post that! haha

Comment: Awesome, this worked. Thanks for your help. Here I was thinking it just had to be more complicated than this.

Answer (score 1):

These fixes will make your menu more mobile proof:

1. Remove `float: right;` from `.navbar-nav` if it's the mobile version of your website. This behavior sorts out the sudden right to left movement.
2. Remove the margin on `.navbar-nav`, and give it a width of 100%.